# не работает скрытие элементов при нажатии на кнопку jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

необходимо скрывать элементы списка если их чекбокс checked

ф-ция скрытия

```
$(".done").click(function(){

    if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
         $(this).parents('#list-items').css('display', 'none');

    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

то как элементы добавляются

```
$('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
```

html

```
<body>

<ul id="list-items"></ul>
<form class="add-items">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-list-item" placeholder="task?">
  <button class="add" type="submit">add</button>
</form>
<button class="sort">sort</button>
<button class="done">close</button>
<script src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

[image: само приложение]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `$(".done").click` `this` у вас это ссылка на кнопку по которой был клик. А Вам по клику надо найти `checkbox` и скрыть их.

```js
$('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + "1" + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");

$('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + "2" + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");

$('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + "3" + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");

$(".done").click(function(){
$('#list-items input:checked').parent().css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-items">
  
</ul>
<form class="add-items">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-list-item" placeholder="task?">
  <button class="add" type="submit">add</button>
</form>
<button class="sort">sort</button>
<button class="done">close</button>
```